# How to resize an image after upload it in ASP.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

I try to upload an image and save it on my host then immediately resize it and save the new image to another place on my host. here is my code:

> ---------------btnStart()-----------------

```
    //1-get web path
    string path = Server.MapPath("..") + "\\images\\";
    string thumbPath = Server.MapPath("..") + "\\thumbnails\\";
    path += folder;
    thumbPath += folder;
    //2-get and check file extension
    String[] validext = { ".jpg", ".png" };
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadPicture.PostedFile.FileName);
    if (Array.IndexOf(validext, ext.ToLower()) < 0)
    {
        lblMessage.Text ="this file is not allowed";
        return;
    }
    //3-get and check file size
    long size = UploadPicture.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    size = size / 1024;
    if (size > 1300)
    {
        lblMessage.Text ="incorrect size";
        return;
    }
    //4-get file name
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(UploadPicture.PostedFile.FileName);
    lblFileName.Text = filename;
    //5-check file exist and if (true) generate new name
    while (System.IO.File.Exists(path + "\\" + filename))
    filename = "1" + filename;

    //6-save file to server
    UploadPicture.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + filename);
    changeImageSize cis = new changeImageSize();
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path + filename);
```

> -----------end event-------------------- 
>   -----------changeImageSize class--------

```
public class changeImageSize
{
public changeImageSize() { }
/// <summary>
/// Method to resize, convert and save the image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">Bitmap image.</param>
/// <param name="maxWidth">resize width.</param>
/// <param name="maxHeight">resize height.</param>
/// <param name="quality">quality setting value.</param>
/// <param name="filePath">file path.</param>      
public void Save(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int quality, string filePath)
{
    // Get the image's original width and height
    int originalWidth = image.Width;
    int originalHeight = image.Height;

    // To preserve the aspect ratio
    float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;
    float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;
    float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    // New width and height based on aspect ratio
    int newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
    int newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);

    // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
    ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = this.GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // Create an Encoder object for the Quality parameter.
    Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;

    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    // Save the image as a JPEG file with quality level.
    EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
    encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
    newImage.Save(filePath, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
}

/// <summary>
/// Method to get encoder infor for given image format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="format">Image format</param>
/// <returns>image codec info.</returns>
private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat format)
{
    return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().SingleOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
}
}
```

> -----------end class--------------------

as you see on btnStart() event code , i want after uploading an image, make an copy with new size and save it to another folder(thumbnail).
but I get an error as bellow :

[image: error scence]

Comment: can you verify permission on directories where you are writing files.

Comment: i want save both of them on my host :
first the original file must save on root/images<br>
second after uploading original I want resize it and save new one on root/thumbnail

Comment: Directory access should be available to IIS_IUSR / IUSR for writing to disk. However, you can check if you get the new resized image in debug mode to verify if there is some other issue.

Comment: I am asking for actual physical location on host where files are being written, in our case it may be *path* or *thumbPath* variable value. This could be permission issue. please check read/write permissions on respective location.

Comment: how big your image is?

Comment: sorry but how can I define read/write permissions on respective location?

Comment: the big image can be every images that user can upload it

Comment: GDI sure sucks.  Cryptic error messages!

Comment: well, what i must to do?

Comment: @BlueMoon To set permissions on a directory, right-click it in Windows Explorer, choose "Properties", look under the "Security" tab, and click the "Edit" button.

Comment: @BlueMoon Incidentallly, you've forgotten to do `newImage.Dispose()`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton, I check the permissions for both directory and they was on full control :(

Comment: and newImage.Dispose() doesn't work and same error

Comment: Check `filePath`. Is it what you think it should be?

Comment: file path is the path of Orignal pics that will upload and it's ok, I checked it.

Comment: @BlueMoon I meant the value of the variable `filePath` in the line `newImage.Save(filePath, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well. Just check following:

1) Your image is not corrupted.

2) Try to specify different quality levels 25, 50, 75.

3) maxWidth, maxHeight you specified cannot be used in this case.

4) Check your file paths.

Edit:

I set quality level to 75 for 1920x1080 image, and tried to set maxWidth and maxHeight to 800x600, 320x240. It works well.

```
        ChangeImageSize cis = new ChangeImageSize();
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Alex Len Paul\Desktop\1\1920x1080.jpg");
        cis.Save(b, 320, 240, 75, @"C:\Users\Alex Len Paul\Desktop\1\1920x1080_2.jpg");
```

Comment: I just follow your code instead of your paths I just set my own path but doesn't work for me and same error again :(

Comment: Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(path + filename);
cis.Save(bm, 320, 240, 75, thumbPath);

Comment: Give me your image you are trying to resize.

Comment: look, I try any images and result same error, for example I just try upload one of pics in windows/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg or another time I try somewhere eles on another partition.

Comment: Hm, those pictures resizes on my machine, it seems file cannot be written. Try to save image without resizing and save everything like text files. If it doesn't work then the problem in access.

Comment: thanks for your guide but I already try it without resize commands but get same damn gdi+ error :((

Answer (score 1):

I think It's because of saving folder on host, you must grant writing permission to saving path on your host. your code can't save image in host

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Explaining why this is and/or providing references/examples would improve your answer.  Also please take care to use proper grammar/capitalization.